# Why oracle package does not allow tables or views declaration

Tags: oracle11g, package

Inside an oracle package, we are allowed to declare functions and procedures to logically group them. Now why a package does not allow tables and views but only functions and procedures? Or more importantly, how can I logically group tables and views for better understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions and procedures are code. They are compiled (either when you create them or on demand). They are transient, and can be discarded, recompiled. If your package has state, each session can have its own copy of a package.

Tables are permanent data structures. They are not compiled. You do not declare a table, you create it. Putting one inside a package just makes no sense.

If you want a way to visualize the relationships between tables, etc., you can try the [Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html) in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

Because it doesn't make much sense.
Use prefixes, suffixes and power of your IDE to get view of the tables, you like.